# How to Call this Method from OnCreate - Android C# Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I am wondering how I am meant to Call `public static async Task CopyAssetAsync(Activity activity)` from the OnCreate method.

```
  public static async Task CopyAssetAsync(Activity activity)
    {
        {
            var notesPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "NotesData.txt");

            if (!File.Exists(notesPath))
            {
                try
                {
```

**UPDATE 1:**

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            ActionBar.Hide();

            btnAdd = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnAdd);
            //Notes
            notesList = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lvNotes);


            //Where I am trying to call the method...
            CopyAssetAsync();
```

**UPDATE 2:**

[image]

Comment: show your onCreate method

Comment: See Update 1 for OnCreate Method

Comment: your method has 1 parameter, why you didn't pass it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use await keyword while calling and make the `OnCreate()` method `async` :

```
protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
    ActionBar.Hide();

    btnAdd = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnAdd);
    //Notes
    notesList = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lvNotes);


    //Where I am trying to call the method...
     await CopyAssetAsync(this);
}
```

Comment: You need to pass the Activity type reference as you have declared as parameter. If you are in activity pass "this" as current activity.

Comment: If this worked for you, please accept and upvote the answer.

Comment: I've always read that you shouldn't ever write an "async void" method. Instead you should be returning "async Task" instead. But I've seen in several articles where people are overriding the OnCreate method and making it "async void". Does Xamarin work differently when it comes to async/await methods then other supported platforms? Thanks! :)